# Printing from 14.04 on Canon MG6350

Tags: drivers, printing

I cannot get printing to a Canon Pixma MG6350 work on my HP255 G1 running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.  The printer wakes up but does not print.  Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

stuart, and you visits this page.

https://launchpad.net/~michael-gruz/+archive/ubuntu/canon-trunk/+packages

this article, is solution for install driver for printer mg6350.
http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-drivers-for-canon-printers-pixma-mg-series-on-ubuntu-14-0413-1013-0412-1012-04-linux-mint-16151413-pear-os-87-and-elementary-os-0-2/

good luck.

Bye.

Comment: Please try to include the solution into your answer instead of just linking to other sites.